# React Mobx edit observable array

Tags: reactjs, observable, mobx

I'm learning Mobx and I'm trying to build a form application which displays some fields of an array and you should be able to edit them.

I have an array `@observable myArray`, how can I edit a certain field of that array?

I tried making the function:

```js
@action setMyArray(id, value) => {
   myArray.map(field => {
      if (field.id === id) {
          field.text = value
      }
   }
}
```

When I use this as a callback method for a text field, it only adds 1 letter to the current value of field and does not rerender in the textfield.

Comment: Please post all relevant code. Where this is being called etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have to store data in a array
If you want to store all form fields in one observable field, you should use for example object or Map, like that:

```js
class SomeStore {
  @observable formData = new Map();

  @action
  setValue = (name, value) => {
    this.formData.set(name, value)
  }
}
```

and then you can use such code for react component

```js
const onChange = (event) => {
  SomeStore.setValue(event.target.name, event.target.value);
}

return (
  ...
    <input name="firstName" onChange={onChange} value={SomeStore.formData.get('firstName')} />
    <input name="lastName" onChange={onChange} value={SomeStore.formData.get('lastName')} />
  ...
)
```